# intellij plugin development show input dialog with multiple text boxes

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm creating intelliJ plugin and registering my action , inside my action i want to show an input dialog with multiple text boxes, how do I do that ?
I have an example of showing only one text box -

```
 String txt= Messages.showInputDialog(project, "What is your name?", 
                                     "Input your name", Messages.getQuestionIcon());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new GUI Form (form + class). Class should extend `DialogWrapper` and override methods.

Inside `createCenterPanel()` return your root JPanel. You can set any default values, add event listeners to text box, etc., before returning JPanel.

Implement an `Action` interface where you want to get the value when OK button is clicked. Pass this action to your form class.

`getOKAction()` should return this action.

Following code is from a plugin i'm currently working on. Hopefully this will give you some idea but will have to adapt it to your need.

```
public class ReleaseNoteDialog extends DialogWrapper implements Action {
    private JTextArea txtReleaseNote;
    private JPanel panelWrapper;

    .......
    protected JComponent createCenterPanel() {
        ......
        return panelWrapper;
    }
    ......
    @Override
    protected Action getOKAction() {
         return this;
    }
    .......
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // save value to project state
        super.doOKAction();
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @AKT with extending the `DialogWrapper` but suggest overriding `doOKAction`:

```
@Override
  protected void doOKAction() {
    if (getOKAction().isEnabled()) {
      // custom logic
      System.out.println("custom ok action logic");

      close(OK_EXIT_CODE);
    }
  }
```

Or, if you just want your data out without the Action mess, add a custom method:

```
public class SearchDialog extends DialogWrapper {

  ...

  public String getQuery() {
    return "my custom query";
  }
}
```

You can use it like:

```
SearchDialog dialog = new SearchDialog();
dialog.showAndGet(); // Maybe check if ok or cancel was pressed
String myQuery = dialog.getQuery();
System.out.println("my query: " + myQuery);
```